# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "F:/TextFiles/loginaccs.txt"

Tags: java

```
final String FileName = "F:/TextFiles/loginaccs.txt";
    InputStream FileNameIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileName.getBytes());
    try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(FileNameIS));
        int NoOfUsers = Integer.parseInt(file.readLine());
        String[][] Accounts = new String[NoOfUsers][2];
        for (int i=1; i>NoOfUsers; i++) {
            Accounts[i][1] = file.readLine();
            Accounts[i][2] = file.readLine();
        }
        for (int i=1; i>NoOfUsers; i++) {
            System.out.println(Accounts[i][1]);
            System.out.println(Accounts[i][2]);
        }
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: unable to read file.");
        e.printStackTrace();   
    }
```

This is my code, was trying to read some data out of a text file which goes as follows: 
(F:/TextFiles/loginaccs.txt")

```
4
Tom
123456
Mary
12345
Peter
1234
D3K
123
```

Then the console says there is some kind of exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "F:/TextFiles/loginaccs.txt"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.RPGOfTheCorrupted.Program.Main.Login(Main.java:27)
at com.RPGOfTheCorrupted.Program.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

I have no idea why would that happen, and can someone answer me if there is any problem with the program?
Much thx.

Comment: You're trying to parse the contents of the file **name**, not the contents of the file itself.

Answer (score 4):

You are not reading from a `File`, you are reading from a `String` (representing the name of the file) :

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(FileNameIS));
```

Try this :

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FileName)));
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. To be honest I just started learning Java today so I am  basically a "noob", you know.

Comment: We all where, and we all made such mistakes :)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(FileName.getBytes());
```

is setting up an input stream using the bytes of the *name* of your file, not the contents. I would investigate using a [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) or similar

Comment: Probably sour grapes

Comment: Given the other correct answer has been downvoted, I suspect you're right

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the problems pointed out by others, your issue is on this line:

```
for (int i=1; i>NoOfUsers; i++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<NoOfUsers; i++) {
```

Additionally, don't forget that indexes in Java start from 0 and go to size-1. Therefore in an array of 2 elements, you have element 0 and element 1. So the lines:

```
Accounts[i][1] = file.readLine();
Accounts[i][2] = file.readLine();
```

should be

```
Accounts[i][0] = file.readLine();
Accounts[i][1] = file.readLine();
```

Comment: No it's not. OP is never opening the file for input.

Comment: @Pickle Downvotes happened before the edit... I've reversed mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since

```
  new ByteArrayInputStream(FileName.getBytes());
```

returns the content of your file but your are expecting your file name.

try this instead:

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FileName)));
```

Comment: How does this add value over the other answers from 10 minutes ago?